# Changing attribute type - data bind Spring MVC Form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, data-binding

Let's say I have the following:

Hibernate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "companyId")
    private Integer companyid;
```

My JSP:

```
<form:form commandName="user" id="userForm">
<form:input path="name" />
<form:input path="companyId" />
```

Now I would like to show the company name in the text field rather than its id.
And when I submit the form, at some point, I query the company id by providing its name to populate and persist the entity. I want to be able to do the other way around.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to hide the `companyId` in your jsp:

```
<form:form commandName="user" id="userForm">
<form:input path="name" />
<form:hidden path="companyId" />
<form:input path="companyName" />
```

With this, you will be able to show `companyName` in your JSP and to receive both in your controller.

Comment: But companyName is not an attribute of Users nor UserDto.So when I insert path="companyName"  I get this exception: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'companyName' of bean class [UserDto]...

Comment: Then you need to have the `Company` object inside `User` to show this field (`path="company.name"`). You're using JPA/Hibernate, so it's easy to achieve this (with @OneToOne, @ManyToOne) and would be a good implementation.